# Referencing equations with multiple labels

Tags: equations, numbering

I want to typeset an equation that's equivalent (but not identical) to a previous equation, numbering both of them individually but acknowledging the equivalence.  I'm doing this as follows:

```
\begin{align}
y &= x
\label{eq1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
y &= z
\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{{\theequation}, =  \ref{eq1}}
\label{eq2}
\end{align}
```

What I'm aiming for (and get) is output something like

```
y = x    (1)
text blah blah blah
y = z    (2,=1)
```

My problem is that I want to cite the second equation as

```
Using eqtn~\ref{eq2} never works
```

to get

```
Using eqtn 2 never works
```

but what i actually get is

```
Using eqtn 2,=1 never works.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you might consider numbering them "1" and "1'".  then `\tag{\ref{eq1}$'$}` would give you something that makes sense in text.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would help readers: two numbers for the same equation could be confusing.

If the first appearance of the equation is in some introductory material, I'd leave it unnumbered, explaining that it will reappear as “equation (3)” or whatever.

However, here's a way to do as you wish. Try it and think again whether using it.

The idea is to locally change the `\tagform@` command that's responsible for typesetting the equation numbers, calling `\tag{\theequation}` after stepping

***Warning*** Don't type `\eqref` in the argument to `\specialtag`, because it uses `\tagform@`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\amsmath@tagform@\tagform@
\newcommand{\specialtag}[1]{%
  \def\tagform@##1{\amsmath@tagform@{##1#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=1\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1=1\specialtag{, = \ref{eq1}}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

Let's see: \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For `fleqn` it's much more complicated and I couldn't find a general solution; the following works for `equation`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@specialtag
\newcommand{\specialtag}[1]{%
  \global\@specialtagtrue
  \gdef\@thespecialtag{#1}%
}
\def\endmathdisplay@fleqn{%
  $\hfil\hskip\@mathmargin\egroup
  \ifnum\badness<\inf@bad \let\too@wide\@ne \else \let\too@wide\z@ \fi
  \ifx\@empty\df@tag
  \else
    \setbox4\hbox{%
      \if@specialtag\@xp\def\@xp\theequation\@xp{\theequation\@thespecialtag}\fi
      \df@tag
      \global\@specialtagfalse
      \ifx\df@label\@empty \else \@xp\ltx@label\@xp{\df@label}\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \csname emdf@%
    \ifx\df@tag\@empty U\else \iftagsleft@ L\else R\fi\fi
  \endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=1\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1=1\specialtag{, = \ref{eq1}}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

Let's see: \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, very neat.   But I'm using fleqn, and that seems to break your solution...?

Comment: @ionh I'm not clairvoyant.

Comment: @ionh With `fleqn` the printing of the equation number is made very differently and at a different timing. Maybe it's possible to fix this for `equation`, but I'm inclined to think it's *very* difficult for the other alignment environments.

Comment: Ah, thanks...sorry, i just use fleqn as a "black box" and hadn't appreciated that it would have knock-on consequences :(